# How to make huffman tree in scheme?

Tags: tree, scheme, huffman-code

I am trying to make huffman encoding/decoding in scheme so i have function "frequencies" which makes frequencies list.
I made also function which found the the pair form the list with the smallest frequencies and a function which remove the pair with the smallest frequencies from the list.
And i dont understand how to make the tree.
And when i have the tree how to start encoding?
I also have funct.which combine the two pairs with the smallest frequencies into one pair like this
(a.3) (b.5) ->((a b).8)

Answer (score 3):

You'll discover a very detailed explanation of [Huffman Encoding Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) in section [2.3.4](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html#%_sec_2.3.4) of the classic book [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html), available online. There you'll find a description of the inner workings of such a tree, along with a complete implementation. You'll only need to adapt it to the interfaces/data structures provided for your assignment.

Comment: @user3050163 did you run the code examples? you won't find a finer explanation of Huffman encoding trees in Scheme than the one found in SICP. Which part of the code, exactly, you didn't understand?

Comment: i don't understand the making of the three...before the coding.
how the three must look like,with what arguments and s.o.